# Locating image in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to check if a logo (image) is displayed or not but i am unable to find out the xpath for the same.The html code is as below:

```
 <div class="page-wrapper">
 <a class="brand pull-left" href="www.com">The Logo<\a>
```

What could be the possible xpath for verifying "The Logo " is displayed.

Comment: `//a[@class=".brand pull-left" and .="The Logo"]`

Comment: @Rkstr22 is there any kind of AJAX (delayed loading) going on?

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=52ae0a4a-904d-45e9-ac0a-50974bb29c08-xpath

Comment: @nathan no there is nothing like that happening

Answer (score 1):

May one of these works:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'The Logo')]

//a[contains(text(), 'The Logo') and @href='www.com']

//div[@class='page-wrapper']/a[contains(text(), 'The Logo')]

//div[@class='page-wrapper']/a[contains(text(), 'The Logo') and @href='www.com']
```